# How do I change the hostname in a cutomized live-cd Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: hostname, custom-distributions

I have customized a 20.04 live-cd using Cubic.  I need help with changing the hostname to `obo`.  No matter what method I've tried it always defaults back to 'Ubuntu'.

Using Cubic's CHROOT terminal, I've tried:

- copying both modified hostname and host files to `/etc/`
- `echo obo /etc/rc.local`
- `@reboot * * * root hostnamectl set-hostname obo` in crontab

None of the above have worked.  I am able to set the hostname post boot i.e. once desktop has loaded.  If it makes a difference I've bypassed "Try Ubuntu".

Any help, suggestions, comments to get the hostname set at or during boot-time are very much appreciated.

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization#Removing%20the%20%28Casper%29%20Autologin  "Boot init"

Comment: @Rinzwind, thanks for the sugggestion, I wasn't able to get this to work.  I accessed the casper file using Cubic virtual environment, setting hostname didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to do this is to add the `hostname` boot parameter to your boot configurations files.

---

**Approach**

For UEFI boot in Ubuntu 20.04...

- Edit `boot/grub/grub.cfg`
- Note that the section 'menuentry "Ubuntu"' is used for the default option

For Legacy BIOS boot in Ubuntu 20.04...

- Edit `isolinux/txt.cfg`
- Note that the section 'label live' is used for the default option

However, to keep things simple, just add this parameter to all default (filtered) boot configuration files listed on Boot tab of Cubic's Options page.

Note: The files you see on the Boot tab may be different depending on your flavor or version of Ubuntu. For example, for XUbuntu 20.04, only has `/isolinux/txt.cfg`.

---

**Steps**

On the Boot tab of Cubic's Options page...

1. Select `boot/grub/grub.cfg`

   Add the `hostname=MY_HOST_NAME` parameter to the line(s) that start with `liunx`
2. Select `boot/grub/loopback.cfg`

   Add the `hostname=MY_HOST_NAME` parameter to the line(s) that start with `liunx`
3. Select `isolinux/txt.cfg`

   Add the `hostname=MY_HOST_NAME` parameter to the line(s) that start with `append`

---

**Example**

Here is an example of what the `isolinux/txt.cfg` should look like. In Ubuntu 20.04, this file is used for Legacy BIOS boot.

```
default live
label live
  menu label ^Try Ubuntu without installing
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append boot=casper hostname=SILVERSPR file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash ---
label live-nomodeset
  menu label ^Try Ubuntu without installing (safe graphics)
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append boot=casper hostname=SILVERSPR file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash nomodeset ---
label live-install
  menu label ^Install Ubuntu
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append boot=casper hostname=SILVERSPR file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed only-ubiquity initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash ---
label live-install-nomodeset
  menu label ^Install Ubuntu (safe graphics)
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append boot=casper hostname=SILVERSPR file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed only-ubiquity initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash nomodeset ---
label memtest
  menu label Test ^memory
  kernel /install/mt86plus
label hd
  menu label ^Boot from first hard disk
  localboot 0x80
```

---

**Screenshots**

Example of changes to the `boot/grub/grub.cfg` file in Ubuntu 20.04 for UEFI boot...

[image: Changes to the boot/grub/grub.cfg file in Ubuntu 20.04]

Example of changes to the `boot/grub/loopback.cfg` file in Ubuntu 20.04...

[image: Changes to the boot/grub/loopback.cfg file in Ubuntu 20.04]

Example of changes to the `isolinux/txt.cfg` file in Ubuntu 20.04 for Legacy BIOS boot...

[image: Changes to the isolinux/txt.cfg file in Ubuntu 20.04]

Example of Ubuntu 20.04 Live Environment with a custom hostname...

[image: Ubuntu 20.04 Live Environment with Custom Hostname]

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I followed the first instruction set: was not able to get this to work.  The hostname did not set at boot. Too bad this would have been a quick and dirty fix.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your objective-- are you trying to set the host name in the Live environment (when you boot up the ISO), or are you trying to set the host name ~after~ you've installed your OS? The above solution sets the host name in the Live Environment. (If you don't see this host name when you boot into the ISO, you may be updating the wrong file). Let me know what your objective it, and I may be able to suggest a different solution.

Comment: I am trying to set the host name in the Live environment when the iso boots NOT after install. thanks

Comment: Which flavor and version of Ubuntu are you customizing? Which file did you modify when you made the above change?

Comment: Ubuntu desktop 20.04, as you outlined: Cubic's Options page, on the Boot tab, select boot/grub/grub.cfg and add this parameter (hostname=obo) to the line(s) that start with liunx.  as per your example above starting with menuentry "Ubuntu"

Comment: I just realized that UEFI boot and Legacy BIOS boot use different sets of files. I've updated the answer with detailed instructions. This did not work for you initially because `boot/grub/grub.cfg` is for UEFI boot, and you must be booting using Legacy BIOS. Therefore you should edit `isolinux/txt.cfg`; note that for `isolinux/txt.cfg`, you must edit the lines starting with `append`. To keep things simple, just add `hostname=MY_HOST_NAME` to all of the files as shown in the example screenshots.

Comment: Thank you, finally it works.  Thanks for your persistence, I probably should have mentioned legacy boot in the original post.  I will be upgrading the home server this year hopefully, which is where this livecd is currently deployed to.